# Edit EditForm.aspx for all document Libraries in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have more than 50k document libraries in a site collection (including all subsites).

When we upload the document and hit cancel on EditForm.aspx (Mode=Upload), it still uploads the document in checked out status. I want to overright the cancel button (not from ribbon) on EditForm.aspx to delete the document if certain fields are not filled up. How can I do it for all libraries? Can we create a custom EditForm.aspx for all libraries at once?

[image: Doc edit properties while upload]

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer to the similar question.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee87838f-2946-4244-b47a-4deb51c9f0a9/cancel-functionality-on-upload-document

What you essentially have to do is to override the Cancel behavior in JavaScript and call delete item function.